# Open master.do file in R

Tags: r, import, economics

I'd like to know how to convert a ".do" file and use a file directory from the American Economic Association in R. The file appears to be written in Stata. And, while there are plenty of packages to convert .dta and other file types in R, I can't seem to find anyway to convert this particular file structure. Here is a link to the paper/data

https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.p20171100

The read.me file says that we first have to open a "master.do" file, which I guess then makes use of the other files in the directory. I don't have access to Stata, and couldn't get R to open any of the syntax files.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "do" files contain Stata code, not data. They should just be plain-text files so should open in any text editor. Unless the "do" files are doing a lot of data-processing that's required to get the original data into shape you should just be OK reading the `.dta` data file with something like `haven::read_stata()`, no need to use the "do" files just code the equivalent steps in R.

Comment: I've tried a few R packages for stata and am getting errors. But, i'm sure it works, since the file is from a reputable source. As for your suggestion, i get "Failed to parse [filename] This version of the file format is not supported"

Comment: As I said, `master.do` contains Stata commands, not any data, and you should not try to read it with a function that reads stata data. Try the file-reading functions on any `.dta` files that were provided instead.

Comment: You can try to use this `R --> stata` interface: https://github.com/lbraglia/RStata